# Call to undefined function yii\helpers\mb_strlen() even though mbstring is enabled

Tags: yii2, mbstring

I have enabled mbstring in my php.ini.It even shows in phpinfo().But still I am getting this error in yii2.

```
PHP Fatal Error 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Call to undefined function yii\helpers\mb_strlen()
```

Comment: mb_strlen is a global PHP function, why you search it in yii\helpers\ namespace?

Comment: Post the code please!

Comment: Try to `\mb_strlen()`

Answer (score 1):

As @TomaszKane said in comment, `mb_strlen()` is native PHP function, so you need to call it as `mbstrlen()` without specifying the namespace.

Official documentation:

- [mb_strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php)

Also take a look at [yii\helpers\StringHelper](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-stringhelper.html), `mb_strlen()` is used in several places. For example, if you are looking for byte length, there is special method [byteLength()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basestringhelper.html#byteLength%28%29-detail), you can call it like that:

```
use yii\helpers\StringHelper;

...

StringHelper::byteLength($string);
```

It's basically syntactic sugar of `mb_strlen()`.

Comment: Yes it is used in byteLength() thats why its throwing error.I am not using it anywhere ,error is in the base file of yii2 i.e.StringHelper.